# Why do we need 2 "binding" variables when working with ViewBinding in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Let's look at the official [example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments):

```kotlin
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Why are there 2 similar variables: `_binding` and `binding`? Why can't we use one variable?

Comment: @HenryTwist, yes, thank you, this seems so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to have a non-nullable view of the `binding` property for convenience in the rest of the code, but still have the possibility to manage the actual nullable value in `onCreateView`/`onDestroyView` via `_binding`.

The `lateinit` approach in activities is nicer, but with `lateinit` you can't "reset" the binding back to null, so it's not applicable for fragments.

Comment: Or you can just use a nullable one, and then make the first line of any code that uses the variable   binding?.let {  //rest of code here  }  All a matter of preferred style rather than one being right and one wrong.  I prefer working with the nullable one, with the one in the OP's question you get an NPE when other threads call to UI code after onDestroy is called

Comment: But why do we need `"reset" the binding back to null`?

Comment: @JamesBond I'm not knowledgeable enough about android to say for sure, but I think the idea is that a single fragment instance can be attached to several views during its lifetime, so when a view is destroyed it makes sense to no longer hold a reference to it while waiting for the next one to be created